# Qual a diferença entre '@Url.Action' vs 'asp-controller' junto ao 'asp-action'?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core, razor

Estou realizando um projeto em ASP.NET MVC e me surgiu essa dúvida, O Url.Action em uma tag '' (por exemplo numa navbar) pode redirecionar a página passando o método e controller como parâmetro. Entretanto existem os atributos asp-controller (defino o controller) e asp-action (defino o método) que traria o mesmo resultado, isso é possivel?

```
 <ul class="ulMenu">
    <li class="liMenu"><a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a></li>

    <li class="liMenu"><a href='@Url.Action("Index", "Home")'>Home</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na prática não há diferença, a saída gerada será a mesma. O que muda é que auxiliar de marca de ancora é mais semântico com o html, é como se tu escrevesse html puro pra montar tuas tags html